# With Swift's didSet accessor do I still need to hide access to a property

Tags: swift, oop

I know that with typical Object Oriented programming you should not give access to your properties directly, rather have a function that interacts with that private property. With the fact that Swift has a didSet accessor for properties is it necessary to privatize that property or can I leave it not privatized and access it from it's parent

```
private var coins: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        coinsLabel.text = "\(coins)"
    }
}

func setCoins(amount: Int) {
    coins = amount
}

func getCoinsAmount() {
    return coins
}

//Setting the value from the parent
gameHUD.setCoins(amount: 50)

//retrieving the value from the parent
let coins = gameHUD.getCoinsAmount()
```

Or is it bad practice to just leave coins not privatized and set/get it directly from the parent

```
gameHUD.coins = 50
let coins = gameHUD.coins
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you have not provided any public way to read `coins`, just set it. Is that what you want?

Comment: I was just trying to keep the question as focused as possible. If I were to make the coins property private I would've added a public getCoins() func

Comment: In OOP usually you don't want to give access to you *fields* (data members) directly. The mechanism of properties (which is similar in Obj-C or C#) was created exactly to avoid defining setters and getters for every data member.

Comment: @Sulthan So are you saying that I should create a private variable for coins and a have a public property which changes the private variable?

Comment: @RonMyschuk Not at all. Properties already have their own setters and getters you can use and control separately. There is no reason for you to define another getter and setter around them.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, so to clarify...you are agreeing with @PauloMattos and saying I should just leave my properties not private and access them directly. Like my second example in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't. Properties in Swift are a flexible, mature abstraction mechanism. As such, please go ahead and use it to define you public API. No need to export setters and getters.

For instance, tons of public properties are exported by almost any Apple/iOS native framework. Keep in mind that besides the *[property observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262)* you mentioned (i.e., `willSet` and `didSet`) you can also define *[computed properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259)*. As I said before, this is a full-blown abstraction mechanism.